# Why should I use Integer.toString() instead of just printing the Integer?

Tags: java, integer, tostring

I was following a Java tutorial and it was having me do something like:

```
int k = 5;
System.out.println("The number is " + Integer.toString(k));
```

So like a good sport I followed along, but I can't help but wonder, why use that method at all? Seems like a lot of extra typing to get the same functionality as:

```
int k = 5;
System.out.println("The number is " + k);
```

Is there a good reason to use the `toString()` method for non-string data types? And in my specific example, are there any `int` values that can't be auto toString'ed?

Comment: There is no significant difference between the two.  The tutorial may have wanted to emphasize that `toString` is called "under the covers", but, for day-to-day programming it's just additional clutter.

Comment: I already posted an answer earlier, but wanted to point out for casual readers that there are practical cases in which you *must* use Integer.toString(int) and/or other safeguards when concatenating elements into a longer String with the `+` operator.  If you aren't careful, String concatenation with the `+` operator can produce unintended results.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's one of many "safe programming" practices you can adopt to improve clarity and prevent subtle errors which you or a future maintainer of your code could introduce.  Take the following example:

```
private static void printMessage(int k) {
    System.out.println("number" + '=' + k);
}
```

output: `number=5`

Now suppose you want to print the number first and the text last.  All I'm doing is swapping the first and last items in the string concatenation:

```
private static void printMessage2(int k) {
    System.out.println(k + '=' + "number");
}
```

output: `66number`

Oops!  The int value of `=` was added to `k` instead of being concatenated.  One solution is to make the `=` into a `String`.  Another solution is to explicitly convert the `int` to a `String`:

```
private static void printMessage2Safe(int k) {
    System.out.println(Integer.toString(k) + '=' + "number");
}
```

output: `5=number`

"Oh, but I'd never do that, anyway," you say.  "Anyone in their right mind would have just made the `=` part of the other String."  But what if you're implementing part of a basic calculator app, and you want to output the expression and its result?  If you're really trying to be careful, I suppose you'll use `StringBuilder.append()` to concatenate the parts of the expression.  But if not, then I hope you don't write the first implementation of the `display` method below.

```
public class Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        display(2, '+', 3, 5);
        displaySafe(2, '+', 3, 5);
    }

    public static void display(int num1, char operator, int num2, int result) {
        System.out.println(num1 + operator + num2 + '=' + result);
    }

    public static void displaySafe(int num1, char operator, int num2, int result) {
        System.out.println(Integer.toString(num1) + operator + Integer.toString(num2) + "=" + result);
    }

}
```

output:

```
114
2+3=5
```

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a good reason to use the toString() method for non-string data types?

Some people believe it is clearer. esp for beginners who may not realised they do basically the same thing.

Note: In Java 7 update 9, it doesn't create the String first as append(int) looks like this

```
// from AbstractStringBuilder 
public AbstractStringBuilder append(int i) {
    if (i == Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
        append("-2147483648");
        return this;
    }
    int appendedLength = (i < 0) ? Integer.stringSize(-i) + 1
                                 : Integer.stringSize(i);
    int spaceNeeded = count + appendedLength;
    ensureCapacityInternal(spaceNeeded);
    Integer.getChars(i, spaceNeeded, value);
    count = spaceNeeded;
    return this;
}
```

It converts the number strait into the StringBuilder avoiding the need to create a String first.

> And in my specific example, are there any int values that can't be auto toString'ed?

No. All primitive values can be toString'ed.

The only exception I know of is [signalling and quiet Not-A-Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) values as Java doesn't care about such things.  Both appear as "NaN" and there is no way to tell the difference from the toString() (or most functions in Java)

Comment: But note that these signal/NaN values are only used by floating point primitives like `float`/`double`, and not `int`.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("The number is " + Integer.toString(k));
```

In the above print **"The number is "** is string, so **String+(anything)** is **String** only.So in that case no need to call toString() at all.So if you want to print k value only then also no need to call toString() as `S.O.P` internaqlly calls toString().

So finally , we can say unless specifically you want to convert Integer to String you should not call toString() method.

Answer (score 0):

Use the second version. For string concatination expressions like

```
"The number is " + k;
```

javac builds the actual code using StringBuilder as

```
new StringBuilder("The number is ")).append(Integer.toString(k)).toString());
```

so System.out.println simply prints the resulting string, the full code is

```
System.out.println((new StringBuilder("The number is ")).append(Integer.toString(k)).toString());
```

Answer (score -6):

It allows the number to become a String data type so it is all a string. As Mob said though, it's not even an integer to start with. You would have to parse it to an integer before it would become one.

Comment: It doesn't need to be an Integer, since Integer.toString(int) does not expect an Integer.

Comment: println performs this conversion automatically,we don't hAVE TO DO THAT